# Custom modules is not present in Mendel Linux Build

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, mendel-os

I am newer to Mendel Linux development, I have cloned the code using the instructions I found in the below link.

https://coral.googlesource.com/docs/+/refs/heads/master/GettingStarted.md

I have added a custom module in /linux-imx/drivers/mytestdriver
and following changes were made.

Added mytestdriver.c

Added MakeFile

```
obj-$(CONFIG_TEST_MYDRIVER) += mytestdriver.o
```

Added Kconfig file

```
menu "Test Driver"
config TEST_MYDRIVER
    tristate "Test Driver"
    default m
```

Modified /linux-imx/arch/arm64/configs/defconfig

```
CONFIG_TEST_MYDRIVER=m
```

I have rebuilt the code using `m docker-linux-imx`and `FETCH_PACKAGES=true m` , and found the following logs.

```
  CC [M]  drivers/mytestdriver/mytestdriver.o
  CC      drivers/mytestdriver/mytestdriver.mod.o
  LD [M]  drivers/mytestdriver/mytestdriver.ko
  INSTALL drivers/mytestdriver/mytestdriver.ko
```

I have flashed the device using fastboot,
`lsmod` not listed the mytestdriver module.
I have checked the folders

```
/lib/modules/4.14.98-imx/kernel 
/lib/modules/4.14.98-imx/extras
```

mytestdriver.ko is not found.

Let me know if  I have missed any steps in this process.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the kind of work you're doing, but it would appear at a quick glance of [this guide](https://github.com/AxelRoudaut/How_to_build_android_kernel_to_load_modules_dynamically) that `fastboot` is used to upgrade the kernel image, but not the loadable kernel modules (.ko files).  If you look at the very very bottom of that guide, you'll see they use `adb push` to put the kernel modules onto the device.